# H2 REGEXP_REPLACE function to get value

Tags: database, function, get, h2, regexp-replace

Here i my sample string:

```html
{"username":"sample_usernme","login":"jack777","groups":[],"emailAddress":"sample@sample.com","company":null,"phone":null,"bindedKeys":["sample_usernme"],"owner":null,"expirationDate":null,"uploadsQuota":null,"downloadsQuota":null,"transfersQuota":null,"maxTransferRateBytesPerSecond":null,"resources":[{"type":"VirtualRemoteFileDescriptor","path":"","accessPermissions":{"fileDownloadingAllowed":true,"fileUploadingAllowed":true,"fileOverwritingAllowed":true,"fileDeletionAllowed":true,"fileAppendingAllowed":true,"fileListingAllowed":true,"fileRenamingAllowed":true,"directoriesListingAllowed":true,"directoryMakingAllowed":true,"directoryDeletionAllowed":true,"subdirectoriesBrowsingAllowed":true},"secured":false,"denied":false,"indexable":false,"name":"ref_proxy"}],"administration":null,"secured":false,"enabled":true,"passwordChangingAllowed":true,"emailFileTransferAllowed":true,"usePhoneAuthentication":false,"ignorePasswordAgingRules":false,"passwordResetRequired":false,"loginRedirection":{"type":"DirectoryRedirection","directory":""},"lastLoginDate":null,"ipAccessVerifier":{"type":"NullVerifier"},"maxUploadsPerSession":null,"maxDownloadsPerSession":null,"webPublicKeyAuthenticationAvailable":true,"webOpenPgpEncryptionAvailable":true,"webQuotasAvailable":true,"webContactsAvailable":true,"webAdHocActivityAvailable":true,"webDropZonesAvailable":true,"webAccountLinkAvailable":true,"webPersonalInformationAvailable":true,"passwordExpirationNotification":null,"otpSharedSecret":null,"notes":"","options":{},"tags":[],"creationDate":1602502466555,"version":3,"passwordHash":"","expired":false,"passwordDate":1602501463354,"passwordHistory":[],"memberOfAnyGroup":false}
```

I would like to get vale "false", after "expired":  at this string using H2 database functions.
It is possible to use REGEXP_REPLACE function to get this value?

Bet regards,